# LLM Agent Executor gives InvalidRequestError "Unrecognized request argument supplied: functions"

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model

I get an error "InvalidRequestError: Unrecognized request argument supplied: functions" for the following code I tried to copy-paste from https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/agents/

The error happens after "agent_executor.run()" line of code.

I used "gpt-35-turbo" model.

```
from langchain.agents import tool
from langchain.agents import OpenAIFunctionsAgent
from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.schema import SystemMessage

# Create LLM
llm = ChatOpenAI(
    model_kwargs={"engine": deployment_name},
    temperature=0.2)

@tool
def get_word_length(word: str) -> int:
    """Returns the length of a word."""
    return len(word)

tools = [get_word_length]

# Prompt
system_message = SystemMessage(content="You are very powerful assistant, but bad at calculating lengths of words.")
prompt = OpenAIFunctionsAgent.create_prompt(system_message=system_message)

# Create Agent
agent = OpenAIFunctionsAgent(llm=llm, tools=tools, prompt=prompt)

# Create Agent Executor
agent_executor = AgentExecutor(agent=agent, tools=tools, verbose=True)

# Run it
agent_executor.run("how many letters in the word educa?")

============


    > Entering new AgentExecutor chain...
    ------
InvalidRequestError: Unrecognized request argument supplied: functions                       
Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[29], line 51
     48 agent_executor = AgentExecutor(agent=agent, tools=tools, verbose=True)
     50 # Run it
---> 51 agent_executor.run("how many letters in the word educa?")
```

Please, help me understand how to fix it

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I found

```
from langchain.agents import Tool
from langchain.agents import initialize_agent
from langchain.agents import AgentType
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory


def get_word_length(word: str) -> int:
    """Returns the length of a word."""
    return len(word)

tools = [Tool(name="GetWordLength", func=get_word_length, description="Returns the length of a word.")]    

memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history")
agent_chain = initialize_agent(tools, llm, agent=AgentType.CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION, verbose=True, memory=memory)

agent_chain.run("how many letters in the word educa?")
```